# Exact value or approximation for double sum function

Tags: probability, factorial, poisson-distribution

I have a function as
\begin{align*}
F = \sum^{\infty}_{i=1} \sum^{\infty}_{j=1} \frac{i!j!}{(i+j)!} \left(e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^{i}}{i!}\right)\left(e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^{j}}{j!}\right)
\end{align*}

I want to find the exact value of F or a way to approximate it.

In fact, by removing the duplicate components, F is similar to
\begin{align*}
F = e^{-2\lambda}\sum^{\infty}_{i=1} \sum^{\infty}_{j=1} \frac{\lambda^{i+j}}{(i+j)!}
\end{align*}

This form is pretty similar to the Power Series Expansion for Exponential Function. However, the double sum makes me confused.

Could anyone give me a hint about it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Umm are you trying to estimate the pmf of $Z = X + Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are Poisson distributed random variables?

Comment: No, if it is only the sum of two poisson, the problem is simple as pmf of Z is also poisson.   However, in the function F, I have no idea how to deal with the factorial of (i+j).

Comment: That's correct. I was asking to see if there is a more interesting interpretation in terms of a new random variable. Often that adds to the mathematical jugglery one can do to solve these problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate this explicitly by collecting equal powers of $\lambda$.

To do so, note that $i+j = n$ for $n\geq 2$ has exactly $n-1$ possible positive integer solutions.

Hence, calculating only the double sum without the factor $e^{-2\lambda}$:

$$\sum^{\infty}_{i=1} \sum^{\infty}_{j=1} \frac{\lambda^{i+j}}{(i+j)!} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=2} (n-1)\frac{\lambda^{n}}{n!}$$
$$= \lambda \sum^{\infty}_{n=2} \frac{\lambda^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} - \sum^{\infty}_{n=2}\frac{\lambda^{n}}{n!}$$
$$= \lambda(e^{\lambda}-1) - (e^{\lambda}-1-\lambda)$$

I leave it up to you to multiply by $e^{-2\lambda}$.

Comment: Thank you. I want to ask another question. How about in the case of $\sum^{\infty}_{i=1} \sum^{\infty}_{j=1} \frac{(i \times j)\lambda^{i+j}}{(i+j)!}$. I tried to figure out the pattern for the multiplication of (ij) but did not succeed. Could you give me some hints?

Comment: @M.bara : You are welcome. I am busy at the moment. You may post the other case as a new question. :-)